# How to redirect to different URLs when we click on each row in the table i.e, click on each row element must redirect to different URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc, mustache

How to redirect to different URLs when we click on each row in the table i.e, click on each row element must redirect to different URLs?

I am working on Mustache Spring MVC framework where the entire data from MOngodb is retrieved onto a placeholder in the view page.So, now I need to be make this data click enable and each data row when clicked need to redirect to different URLs

This is my table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Book Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  {{#books}}
  <tr>

    <td>{{book_name}}</td>

    <td>{{book_details}}</td>

  </tr>
  {{/books}}
</table>
```

Output looks like list of books and its description

Now when I click on book1 it should go to some other URL and when I click on book2 it must go to another URL and so on

Comment: can you show examples for which books redirect to which/different URLs ?

Comment: That's what I need... how to redirect to different URLs

Comment: Please, read this tutorial:  https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood your problem correctly this will solve your problem

Add a field `bool_url` ( say `bookUrl` java specific ) to your `Book` bean. 
While adding `book` to database you need to specify that `book_url` too.

then following will work for you

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    {{#books}}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{book_url}}">{{book_name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{book_details}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/books}}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This must be a quick solution

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Book Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            {{#books}}
            <tr>

                <td onclick="window.location='{{book_url}}';>{{book_name}}</a></td>

                <td>{{book_details}}</td>

            </tr>
            {{/books}}
        </table>
```

Comment: What is {{book_url}} ? How do I use that ?

Comment: the url that you need to trigger,  or try this onclick="window.location='https://example.com?id=12';

Comment: Well, Actually when the above code I have posted is run it displays a list of books and its description in a tabular format. Now, what i am looking for is when I click on each book it should redirect to different URLs

Comment: while clicking on book name or the entire row?

Comment: just book name is fine

Comment: It returns an error 'No method or field with name 'book_url''...... Even I mention an URL and then any click on any book in this page is redirecting to the same URL mentioned, but it each click on book should redirect to different URLs

Comment: @VinayTeja you have to create the attribute with that name

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Here each url will be like `some_url/book_name`.

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <a href="./some_url{{book_name}}">{{book_name}}</a>
   </td>
   <td>{{book_details}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are there any other ways to do this other than inclythe links into the database?